# Receive another remote notification action when handling the previous one

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I searched for a while and didn't see any answers related, so I have to open a new question. Please point out if it is duplicated.

When a user touches a iOS notification action, the following method is sent to the app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

According to the documentation, when the application is done processing the action, the `completionHandler` should be called. So if the process is a asynchronous one, then the delegate method may be something like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(5);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"completed with notification %@", userinfo);
            completionHandler();
        });
    });
}
```

Here, the global queue sleeps for 5 seconds for simulation of the action processing.

With the setting above, I took the following steps:

1. perform action1
2. perform action2 **BEFORE** action1's completionHandler is called.
3. After action2's completionHandler is called, perform action3

After that, I found that the action3's completionHandler **NEVER** be called, which means that the action3 is **NEVER** dealed.

I found this in iOS 9, not sure about other iOS versions.
Why is that? What can I do to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I put the completionHandler execution and the async execution code in the middle of this paired APIs:

```
- beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
```

and

```
- endBackgroundTask
```

to ensure the completionHandler can be invoked in my sequence and will not be suspend when app runs into background mode.

And it works. ^_^